# Changing sender name in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to change my email sender name in Devise but everything I tried do not work. 
Here's what I tried :

```
config.mailer_sender = "Exemple <hello@exemple.io>"
config.mailer_sender = "'Exemple' <hello@exemple.com>"
config.mailer_sender = "\"Exemple\" <hello@exemple.io>"
```

As a sender name, I have "Hello" no matter if I'm on Gmail or Outlook.

Yesterday, to change my email subject, I put :

```
<% message.subject = 'Exemple' %>
```

Is there a chance that something similar exist to change the sender name ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you configure it in `config/initializers/devise.rb` and try restarting your Rails server?

Comment: Yeah, i just tried this ... Doesn't change anything. It makes me crazy because what i wrote seems to work for other people.

Comment: Are you using Gmail or some other service via SMTP to send the emails? I know that Gmail does not let you set the FROM address to prevent it being used as a spam delivery network.

Comment: You were right, restarting Rails server worked. I just didn't notice that email were grouped and the sender's name changed. 
Many thanks guys.